# Obtener posicion de un elemento con jquery o javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen dia, tengo la siguiente duda, espero explicarme:
Quisiera obtener la posicion actual de un elemento dentro de mi pagina web.
Yo lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
ar tops = $("#tblDemo" + idTbl).offset().top;
```

Ahora aqui el detalle es que, si me desplazo con scroll hacia abajo, la posicion sigue siendo la misma, pero quiero saber si hay forma de saber cual es la posicion o la altura actual con respecto al top, sin importar que me desplace con el scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes lograr de la siguiente forma:

```
ar tops = $("#tblDemo" + idTbl).getBoundingClientRect().top
```

Según su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

> El método Element.getBoundingClientRect() devuelve el tamaño de un
>   elemento y su posición relativa respecto a la ventana de visualización
>   (viewport).

Ojalá sea lo que buscas.

Comment: Gracias me sirvio la informacion.

Comment: Un gusto ser de ayuda.

Comment: Una duda, si quisiera ahora posicionar un elemento pero con respecto a la ventana de visualizacion se puede realizar?

Comment: No entiendo bien la pregunta.